# how to pass Future<int> to super class

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I am trying to learn Flutter and BLoC pattern. So, I created a simple counter app. Initially count value is 0 and it increases/decreases as respective buttons are pressed. The initial value(zero) is sent to the initial state as follows.

```
class CounterBloc extends Bloc<CounterEvent, CounterState> {
  CounterBloc() : super(CounterInitialState(0));
```

The Counter app worked as expected, but whenever I restart the app count starts from zero. Now I wish to start the count from where I left. I read about SharedPreferences and could successfully save the current value. But I can't load the value and send it to `CounterInitialState()`(The argument type 'Future' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'). How can I achieve this?

My counter_bloc.dart looks like this;

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';
import 'package:sampleOne/config/config.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
part 'counter_event.dart';
part 'counter_state.dart';

class CounterBloc extends Bloc<CounterEvent, CounterState> {
  CounterBloc() : super(CounterInitialState(0));

  @override
  Stream<CounterState> mapEventToState(
    CounterEvent event,
  ) async* {
    if (event is CounterIncrementEvent) {
      yield* _mapIncrementEvent(event.countVal); 
    }
    if (event is CounterDecrementEvent) {
      yield* _mapDecrementEvent(event.countVal);
    }
  }
}

Stream<CounterState> _mapIncrementEvent(val) async* {
  await saveData(val);
  yield CounterIncrementState(val + 1);
}
Stream<CounterState> _mapDecrementEvent(val) async* {
  await saveData(val);
  yield CounterDecrementState(val + 1);
}


Future<bool> saveData(int val) async {
  SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  return pref.setInt('key', val + 1);
}



Future<int> loadData() async {
  SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  return pref.getInt('key') ?? 0;
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to wrap your widget with a FutureBuilder widget.
for example

```
FutureBuilder<int>(
  future: _bloc.loadData(),
  initalData: 0,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    return Text(snapshot.data.toString());
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Where do you call loadData()?

Maybe you need to to put an await before like this:

```
Future<int> data = loadData();
int data = await loadData();
```

Your function is asynchronous so it returns a Future, add await to get an integer

Comment: `await` works only with async keyword. This didn't work